# Selenium WebDriver C#: Exception Thrown Finding Element With SVG using XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Here is an my HTML element I'm trying to find:

```
<div class="q02Nz _0TPg" data-testid="new-post-button" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
<svg aria-label="New Post" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
<path d="M31.8 48H16.2c-6.6 0-9.6-1.6-12.1-4C1.6 41.4 0 38.4 0 31.8V16.2C0 9.6 1.6 6.6 4 4.1 6.6 1.6 9.6 0 16.2 0h15.6c6.6 0 9.6 1.6 12.1 4C46.4 6.6 48 9.6 48 16.2v15.6c0 6.6-1.6 9.6-4 12.1-2.6 2.5-5.6 4.1-12.2 4.1zM16.2 3C10 3 7.8 4.6 6.1 6.2 4.6 7.8 3 10 3 16.2v15.6c0 6.2 1.6 8.4 3.2 10.1 1.6 1.6 3.8 3.1 10 3.1h15.6c6.2 0 8.4-1.6 10.1-3.2 1.6-1.6 3.1-3.8 3.1-10V16.2c0-6.2-1.6-8.4-3.2-10.1C40.2 4.6 38 3 31.8 3H16.2z"></path>
<path d="M36.3 25.5H11.7c-.8 0-1.5-.7-1.5-1.5s.7-1.5 1.5-1.5h24.6c.8 0 1.5.7 1.5 1.5s-.7 1.5-1.5 1.5z"></path>
<path d="M24 37.8c-.8 0-1.5-.7-1.5-1.5V11.7c0-.8.7-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.7 1.5 1.5v24.6c0 .8-.7 1.5-1.5 1.5z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

I found the XPath by hovering over the element, right clicking and selecting Copy XPath in the Chrome Driver window. Here is my code line.

```
ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/svg"));
```

The Chrome Driver throws an NoSuchElementException. How can I get this element so I can click on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='New Post']
```

With svg, use "name" and then go from there.

```
WebElement myLink = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//*[name()='svg' and @aria- label='New Post']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.click(myLink).build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks Dazed. I used the code you suggested and the driver found the element, but when I call `ele.Click();` the driver throws a timeout exception "click timed out after 60 seconds." I tried using `ele.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);` but get an ElementNotInteractableException. Any ideas on this?

Comment: use something like Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='New Post']")).Click();

Comment: I tried that. driver throws a timeout exception "click timed out after 60 seconds."

Comment: Updated my answer a bit. Try that.

Comment: Same thing... `The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54728/session/13fd1d03de2655b99aa9bf258b30d476/actions timed out after 60 seconds.`

Comment: any iframes involved? is this a public facing site I can see?

Comment: It's the + round circle image on Instagram to add a new image to my account. The keys (CTRL + SHIFT + I) and (CTRL + SHIFT + M) has been sent to the window and I'm trying to click on the + round circle image to bring up the file dialog to set an image file to add to Instagram.

Comment: I played with this a bit and had no luck. Kind of odd. I ran a bool on if the element was there and it was. When clicking it nothing. Makes me wonder about using an offset on the click.

Comment: Hi Dazed. Can you try to see if you can get click to work in your sandbox test? I appreciate it.

Comment: I tried it for a few hours and I was not able to get the click so I am rather perplexed. The element is found and I tried various offsets, java clicks etc. and it always timed out.